# Need help understaing how preg_match works in php

Tags: php, regex

I am new to using preg_match and I am having a hard time trying to grasp it. For example for this code below.. It only returns one match which is "h" .. isn't is supposed to return an array of 3 key value pairs?

```
$subject = "hey";
preg_match("/[a-z]/", $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Dammit @hwnd, you copied my groove.

Comment: possible duplicate of [preg\_match returns identical elements only once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929398/preg-match-returns-identical-elements-only-once)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To return more matches you use [preg_match_all()](https://www.php.net/preg_match_all) instead,

```
$subject = "hey";
preg_match_all("/[a-z]/", $subject, $matches); 
print_r($matches);
```

This would print,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => h
            [1] => e
            [2] => y
        )

)
```